# Very high latency on LAMP VPS Server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I have a Godaddy VPS Server with 2GB RAM serving mobile clients over HTTPS. From the logs, the server is serving an average of 5 requests per second throughout the day.

I am able to ssh to the server and work normally on the terminal.  But, I am not able to open any page on the server using the browser. It always times out with `Server is taking too long to respond` error. Opening a raw http connection using putty also times out.

The output of top command is :

```
top - 12:55:46 up 11:54,  1 user,  load average: 0.16, 0.12, 0.09
Tasks: 296 total,   1 running, 295 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  1.3%us,  0.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 98.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   2097152k total,  1140276k used,   956876k free,        0k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,        0k cached
```

My apache prefork config is :

```
StartServers       10
MinSpareServers    10
MaxSpareServers    50
ServerLimit        250
MaxClients        250
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
```

How can I figure out what is causing such high latency? Can it be due to the use of HTTPS as I have another server with similar config server 40 requests per second (but HTTP and not HTTPS) without latency when accessed using a browser?

Comment: Are you able to provide output from `service httpd fullstatus` while the server's latency is high? Based on the resource output provided, you aren't hitting any obvious resource limitations. It's also likely the VPS node could be suffering performance issues.

Comment: `/etc/init.d/httpd fullstatus` gives `ELinks: Receive timeout`

Comment: Do you mean you cannot access any of the web pages being served by this server from a remote workstation browser?  What happens if you use telnet and do telnet <yourserverbame> 80  <enter> GET /index_of_your_site.html HTTP/1.1 <press enter twice> ?  Are you accessing by Hostname or IP?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could figure out the issue and resolve it.

The SSL certificate on one of the hosted domain had expired. Once that certificate was updated, the server slowly returned to responsive state.